# Mulesoft dataweave for MongoDB $match and $group

Tags: mongodb, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a running MongoDB group command and its Dataweave code:
MongoDB filter: <-- I am trying to do aggregate of UpdateDate field from "item" collection:

```js
db.item.aggregate([
                   {$group:{_id:"$UpdateDate", count:{ $sum: 1}}},
                   {$sort: {_id:-1}} ,
                   {$limit : 5}
])
```

Its working dataweave code is:

```js
[
{"\$group" : {"_id": "\$" ++ payload.datecolumn, count:{"\$sum":1}}},
{"\$sort": {"_id":-1}},
{"\$limit" : 5}
]
```

Here payload.datecolumn at runtime will come as UpdateDate from property values

Problem in above group command was that:
(a) It does not filter for last 5 days, so it scans for entire data
(b) Group is happening with "Timestamping" due to which I get multiple row for a same date

So applying both above condition my new MongoDB condition which is working is:

```js
db.item.aggregate(\[
{$match: { UpdateDate: { $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime()-6*24*60*60*1000) } } },
{$group:{\_id:{$dateToString:{format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$UpdateDate"}}, count:{ $sum: 1}}},
{$sort: {\_id:-1}},
{$limit : 5}
\])
```

by using "match", we can address point (a)
by using "$dateToString", we were able to remove timestamp. Hence grouping works fine.

can you suggest how to amend my above dataweave code?

Trying to amend my dataweave to handle $match and $dateToString with "%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: The question is confusing. Please edit your question to add: 1) input of the DataWeave script, 2) actual output, 3) expected output, 4) explain what `-6*24*60*60*1000` is supposed to be. Don't expect others to guess what your code is doing.

Comment: Also provide the full DataWeave script you are using. The snippet shown doesn't has an output format.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions it seems that you need to set the name of one of the keys to the column name and compare that the date value of that column is within 5 days of the current date. I used DataWeave to set a dynamic key name and to calculate the current day (using the now() function) minus 5 days (using a period).

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java  
var datecolumn = "UpdateDate"
---
[
  {
    "\$match": {
      (datecolumn): {
        "\$gte": "new Date(\"" ++ (now() - dw::core::Periods::period({
          days: 5
        })) as String {format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} ++ "\")"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "\$group": {
      "_id": "\$" ++ datecolumn,
      count: {
        "\$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "\$sort": {
      "_id": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "\$limit": 5
  }
]
```

Output

```
[{$match={UpdateDate={$gte=new Date("2024/02/12")}}}, {$group={_id=$UpdateDate, count={$sum=1}}}, {$sort={_id=-1}}, {$limit=5}]
```